# how do you edit "-bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem" (which is used by default) when working with containers in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, padding, gutter

I'm practicing recreating existing websites and I cannot get the padding on the left and right sides to go away. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW1TC.png)When I uncheck the box for" -bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;" it removes the padding. However, how do I update this in my code? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbhdy.png)

I have tried setting the left/ight padding to 0. But, it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
 .ct1 {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 350px;

  }
```

```
<div class="container-fluid ct1">
    <h1>IN-STORE & ONLINE</h1>
    <h4>BLACK Friday 30% OFF-70% OFF EVERYTHING</h4>
    <h4>SHOP NOW </h4>
    <h4>Taxes excluded. Offer applicable in local currency for international customers. Go to Special Offers Page to see Exclusions & Restrictions</h4>
</div>
```